# Reset an SkSpriteNode physics simulation in Swift 3

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

So I'd like to move a square from the bottom left of the screen to the top right. However every time this action happens, the square has a little push towards the right side of the screen and also remains with its previous tilt... Can I just reset its physics simulation?

```
object.removeAllActions()
object.position.y = frame.maxY + 50
object.position.x = frame.miX + 50
```

Comment: can you provide a little more information? I can't figure out what "the square has a little push towards the right side of the screen" means, nor why tilt is involved, at all.

Comment: @Confused holy crap it's you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to reset completely a node's physics:

`object.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody()`

I do this all the time. I find it easier to make a function to do this for me, so that way you don't have to reconfigure the pb each time you want it to be reset:

```
class Player: SKSpriteNode {

  func resetPB() {
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: self.size)
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = UInt(4)
    self.physicsBody?.mass = 35
    // And so on...
  }
}
```

Or if you aren't using a subclass:

```
func resetPlayerPB(_ player: SKSpriteNode) {
  player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: player.size)
  // And so on...
}
```